# Integrate multilple theme for a component in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

We would like to develop a website in Joomla! with products listing & news sections. For products listing, we are preferring Hika Shop, News will be the custom module.

In that, we would like to know , is there any option to use different themes for different product categories.

And likewise, We need the news page to be customized as well based on the product categories. It means just theme needs to be changed.

Please suggest/share your ideas, how we can use a component with two different themes ?

Thanks
Mohamed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so much familiar with Hika Shop But your requirement can be easily achieved using [Virtuemart Shop](http://virtuemart.net/) .

In VM you can create different template for different category, listing , details etc.
Also lot of option it provides compare to Hika Shop. Just take a look at VM features.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Hi Jobin, Thanks for your reply. Added with can you explain is it possible for a custom modules like news, photo galleries. how we can use single component with two themes.

Comment: If you are using VM then you can create different templates for categories as I explained above, you can use custom modules for news,galleries etc with it. Then what is the point of single component with two themes? wht are trying to achieve.?

Comment: Thanks Jobin for the information. We have two products categories and its products. Along with we are having news, videos, photos, pages related to categories. So we have to use different theme(Same Layout, different skins) for these two categories.